# SQL doing math find smallest value and then insert into column

Tags: mysql, sql

i  have 2 table
this is my first table

```
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
|   name    |  squad  | val1 | val2 | result1 | result2 | finalresult |
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Andrew    | alpha   |    1 |    2 |         |         |             |
| Brian     | bravo   |    3 |    4 |         |         |             |
| Chris     | charlie |    5 |    6 |         |         |             |
| Danny     | alpha   |    7 |    8 |         |         |             |
| Elise     | bravo   |    9 |   10 |         |         |             |
| Fransisca | charlie |   11 |   12 |         |         |             |
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

and this is my second table

```
+---------+----------+------+------+
|  squad  | subsquad | val3 | val4 |
+---------+----------+------+------+
| alpha   | air      |    1 |    2 |
| alpha   | land     |    3 |    4 |
| alpha   | sea      |    5 |    6 |
| bravo   | air      |    1 |   -2 |
| bravo   | land     |    3 |   -4 |
| bravo   | sea      |    5 |   -6 |
| charlie | air      |   -1 |    2 |
| charlie | land     |   -3 |    4 |
| charlie | sea      |   -5 |    6 |
+---------+----------+------+------+
```

i want to insert data into result1, result2, and finalresult

```
finalresult = MIN ((val1+val3) * (val2+val4)for every subsquad) 
result1 = val 3 that have smallest value in finalresult
result2 = val 4 that have smallest value in finalresult
```

here's example table that i would like to achieve

```
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
|   name    |  squad  | val1 | val2 | result1 | result2 | finalresult |
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Andrew    | alpha   |    1 |    2 |       1 |       2 |           8 |
| Brian     | bravo   |    3 |    4 |       8 |      -2 |         -16 |
| Chris     | charlie |    5 |    6 |       0 |      12 |           0 |
| Danny     | alpha   |    7 |    8 |       8 |      10 |          80 |
| Elise     | bravo   |    9 |   10 |      14 |       4 |          56 |
| Fransisca | charlie |   11 |   12 |       6 |      18 |         108 |
+-----------+---------+------+------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

and here's what i've done

```
SELECT name, a.squad, val1, val2, result1, result2, ((val1+val3)*(val2+val4)) as finalresult, b.squad, subsquad, val3, val4
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.squad=b.squad
```

Comment: It's unlikely (and, if true, unfortunate) that you have a column called group. But, that aside, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i changed my column from group into squad thanks for the information

Comment: @Reza Isn't the result2 of Brian -2?

Comment: yes my bad thanks for the correection

Comment: @Reza, try to setup sqlfiddle, to get help ASAP

Comment: this could help you for SQLfiddle
Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e995b/1

```
select ad.* from (
SELECT name, a.squad, val1, val2, (val1+val3) as result1, (val2+val4) as result2, ((val1+val3)*(val2+val4)) as finalresult
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b ON a.squad=b.squad
) as ad
inner join ( 
SELECT name, min((val1+val3)*(val2+val4)) as finalresult
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.squad=b.squad
group by name,a.squad
 ) as f
 on ad.name = f.name and ad.finalresult = f.finalresult
```

Comment: thank's i need a few adjustment i need to post result1,result2, and final result into table a also i'm gonna run this every a few minute so it would be better if do some checking result1 and result2 first if it is null

Answer (score 0):

Do `finalresult = MIN ((val1+val3) * (val2+val4)for every subsquad)` for every row on a.squad= b.squad like you have done and rank each group of  name/squad order by finalresult.

```
  select a.name,a.squad,a.val1,a.val2,b.val3 as result1,b.val4 as result2,
  (a.val1+b.val3) * (a.val2+b.val4) as finalresult,
  row_number() over (partition by a.name,a.squad order by (a.val1+b.val3) * (a.val2+b.val4)) 
  from a join b on a.squad=b.squad
```

Then you just select above table with condition rn=1.

```
  select name,squad,val1,val2,result1,result2,finalresult from
  (
    select a.name,a.squad,a.val1,a.val2,b.val3 as result1,b.val4 as result2,
      (a.val1+b.val3) * (a.val2+b.val4) as finalresult,
      row_number() over (partition by a.name,a.squad order by (a.val1+b.val3) * (a.val2+b.val4)) 
      from a join b on a.squad=b.squad
  ) where rn=1
```

In case of the DB version is lower 8.

Just using  @Mohtisham Zubair 's  [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340451/7786739).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  My bad.I didn't consider the DB version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *update* the original table, then the logic would look like:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select t1.*, t2.val3, t2.val4,
               (t1.val1 + t2.val3) * (t1.val2 + t2.val4) as finalresult,
               row_number() over (partition by t1.name, t1.squad order by (t1.val1 + t2.val3) * (t1.val2 + t2.val4)) as seqnum
        from table1 t1 join
             table2 t2
             using (squad)
       ) tt
       on tt.name = t1.name and tt.squad = t1.squad and
          tt.val1 = t1.val1 and tt.val2 = t1.val2
    set t1.result1 = tt.val3,
        t1.result2 = tt.val4,
        t1.finalresult = tt.finalresult
    where tt.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: provided that the DB version is 8

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . There is no reason to think that the OP is *not* using version 8.  It has been out for over two years.

Comment: still we need to ask him or restrict the scope within the answer I think

Comment: my DB version is 5.5.56

Comment: how do i update my original table using @Mohtisham Zubair 's anwser.

Comment: @Reza . . . Shouldn't that question be directed to Mohtisham Zubair?